# Почему мы передаем в функцию ссылку на другую функцию, а не вызываем ее?

Tags: javascript

```js
var arrayOfNumbers = [1, 20, 5, 7, 11, 21, 63, 105, 42];

function compare(a, b) {
  return a - b;
};
console.info(arrayOfNumbers.sort(compare));
```

Может ли кто-то объяснить как это работает и почему `compare` нужно прописывать без скобок?
Я передаю имя функции `compare` в `.sort()` как указатель или как ссылку на `compare`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Написание функции "со скобочками" говорит о вызове функции.
Но компаратор нужно именно передать, вызывать его будет уже движок, передавая сравниваемые параметры.
Передаётся ссылка на объект функции.

Comment: То-есть все-таки ссылка на объект функции... Спасибо большое за ответ.